# Compatability when passing object to class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, extend

Ok, so this might be me being pendantic but I need to know the best way to do something:
(This is psudocode, not actual code. Actual code is huge)

I basically have in my package a class that goes like this:

```
internal class charsys extends DisplayObject {
  Bunch of Variables
  a few functions
}
```

I another class which I intend to add to the timeline I want to create a function like this:

```
public class charlist {
  var list:Array = new Array();
  var clock:Timer = new Timer(6000);
  var temp:charsys;

  function addObj(MC:DisplayObject, otherprops:int) {
     temp=MC;
     temp.props = otherprops;
     list.push(temp)
  }

  function moveabout(e: event) {
     stuff to move the items in list
  }

  function charlist() {
     stuff to initialize the timers and handle them.
  }
}
```

So the question is, is my method of populating this array a valid method of doing it, is there an easier way, can they inherit like this and do I even need to pass the objects like I am?

(Still writing the package, don't know if it works at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an object into a function, but you should be careful of what you are planning to do with that object inside that function. Say, if you are planning to pass only `charsys` objects, you write the function header as such:

```
function addObj(MC:charsys, otherprops:int) {
```

Note, the type is directly put into the function header. This way Flash compiler will be able to do many things.

First, it will query the function body for whether it refers to valid properties of a passed instance. Say, your `charsys` object does not have a `props` property, but has a `prop` property, this typing error will be immediately caught and reported. Also if that `props` is, for example, an int, and you are trying to assign a String value to it, you will again be notified.

Second, wherever you use that function, Flash compiler will statically check if an instance of correct type `charsys` is passed into the function, so if there is no `charsys` or its subclass, a compilation error is thrown.

And third, this helps YOU to learn how to provide correct types for functions, and not rely on dynamic classes like `MovieClip`, which can have a property of nearly any name assigned to anything, and this property's existence is not checked at compile time, possibly introducing nasty bugs with `NaN`s appearing from nowhere, or some elements not being displayed, etc.

About common usage of such methods - they can indeed be used to create/manage a group of similar objects of one class, to the extent of altering every possible property of them based on their corresponding values. While default values for properties are occasionally needed, these functions can be used to slightly (or not so slightly) alter them based on extra information. For example, I have a function that generates a ready-to-place `TextField` object, complete with formatting and altered default settings (`multiline=true` etc), which is then aligned and placed as I need it to be. You cannot alter default values in the `TextField` class, so you can use such a function to tailor a new text field object to your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou Vesper, your feedback was very concise. In this case my added properties will contain elements like direction, speed, strength, defense, and pattern and other per-object settings. As opposed to having to manage and maintain continuity between an array of objects and an array of values. Your information has helped confirm I am on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, I think I would assign values to the properties of the charsys object before passing it into the add method though, rather than passing the properties and having a different class do the property assignment.  If you have some common properties they could either have defaults in charsys class definition or you could set literals in the addObj method.

Comment: The concern I am having is whether it would complain about type issues or stuff. I'll have the script working in a day or so. The basic idea is for a game, on each 'level' in the timeline I will use on-frame code to pass the objects in that frame to the stage class. The stage class will then move the objects independently and handle object collision with the player object.